# Azure ServiceBus Topic with multiple Subscribers - Duplicate messages

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I have an Azure ServiceBus Topic called "IntegrationEvent" with **one** subscription called "TestSubscription". I register two subscribers to this subscription that I have **CompetingConsumers**.

A lot of messages are handled in both subscribers. What do I need to change that this won't happen anymore? I thought every message should be handled only by one subscriber?

Sender:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await SendMessageAsync();
    }

    private static async Task SendMessageAsync()
    {
        var sendClient = new TopicClient("ConnectionString");

        var testBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(
            async id =>
            {
                string jsonMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(id);
                byte[] body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonMessage);

                var messageToSend = new Message(body)
                {
                    CorrelationId = id,
                };

                await sendClient.SendAsync(messageToSend);

            }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 25
            });

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            testBlock.Post(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        }

        testBlock.Complete();
        await testBlock.Completion;
    }
}
```

I use two Subscriber/Consumer (**not** Subscription) listening to IntegrationEvent.

```
class Program
{
    static SubscriptionClient subscriptionClient;

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder("ConnectionString");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(builder.EntityPath))
        {
            builder.EntityPath = "IntegrationEvent";
        }

        subscriptionClient = new SubscriptionClient(builder, "TestSubscription");

        await subscriptionClient.RemoveRuleAsync(RuleDescription.DefaultRuleName);
        await subscriptionClient.AddRuleAsync(new RuleDescription(RuleDescription.DefaultRuleName, new TrueFilter()));

        ListenForMessages();

        Console.Read();
    }

    protected static void ListenForMessages()
    {
        var options = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
        {
            AutoComplete = false,
            MaxConcurrentCalls = 10
        };
        subscriptionClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ReceiveMessageAsync, options);
    }

    private static Task ExceptionReceivedHandler(ExceptionReceivedEventArgs arg)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private static async Task ReceiveMessageAsync(Message arg1, CancellationToken arg2)
    {
        string integrationEvent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(arg1.Body);
        Console.WriteLine($"{ arg1.MessageId}, { arg1.CorrelationId}, {integrationEvent}");
        await subscriptionClient.CompleteAsync(arg1.SystemProperties.LockToken);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important to **understand** how subscriptions work before you attempt anything. There's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions#topics-and-subscriptions) exactly about that. Specifically, [rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions#rules-and-actions) that affect what the subscriptions are going to receive.

Right now your code is set up to receive all messages (catch all rule). Once you create a more specific rules using SQL or Correlation filters, you'll be able to control what each individual subscription will receive. I wrote a [post](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/asb-subs-with-correlation-filters) a while ago that has some of that information.

Comment: Thanks Sean, but aren't filter on a subscription base? I've only one subscription that must catch all but several consumers. If I register two consumers to my single subscription a couple of messages got handled by both consumers. And that I don't understand.

Comment: A message might get handled by more than one consumer if it wasn't completed on time or there was an error. Inspect the value of DeliveryCount system property to confirm that.

Comment: ok thanks, I checked that, but I'm no longer able to reproduce. Yesterday every run did have duplicates, today it's working as expected...